# Generate sequential numbers between 0 and 1 with equal distance

Tags: python, numpy, random, sequential-number

I am generating random variables in my array:
`np.random.rand(5,3,20)`

How can I create the same shape and size but sequentially between 0 and 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval using `linspace` and then `reshape` to shape required as follows:

```
np.linspace(0, 1, 300).reshape(5, 3, 20)
```

Note:

> 'The new shape should be compatible with the original shape'

So let's say,
for `np.linspace(0, 1, t).reshape(x, y, z)` the condition that should be met is `t = x*y*z`

Comment: when I run `np.linspace(0, 1, 300).reshape(5,5,20)` , i get this error: `ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`

Comment: `5*3*20 = 300`, where as `5*5*20 = 500`, you need to provide `shape` whose total elements must be same, that is for `np.linspace(0, 1, t).reshape(x, y, z)` the condition that should be met `t = x*y*z`

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
np.linspace(0, 1, num=5).reshape((5, 3))
```

and set the *num* param to implicitly define how big needs to be your step.

Comment: i get this error `ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged` and where is the value `20` gone?

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
#start:stop:stepj inside np.r_ is interpreted as np.linspace(start, stop, step, endpoint=1) inside of the brackets
np.r_[0:1:300j].reshape(5,3,20)
```